# Not able to login to admin panel after updating curl

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, magento-community, curl

I am not able to login to my website admin panel,I have checked all the possible solutions available on Google,tried to reset the admin password,cleared the cache,done the changes in varien.php as well secure/unsecure url.

I have received one alert message in Magento in PAYMENT METHODS in Configuration-

Your current version of cURL php5 module is 7.29.0, which can prevent services that require TLS v1.2 from working correctly. It is recommended to update your cURL php5 module to version 7.34.0 or higher.
I received this message above for cURL upgradtion from magento,same I asked to my hosting provider to upgrade it on server,from then after the upgradation I am not able to login to my admin panel.Is there any thing that I missed to make changes.Or this is not the possible case for not login.
Curl version is now upgraded to 7.36.0
Please help.